# Is there any caching proxy server for Android?

Tags: android, caching, proxy

My Internet bandwidth is low and I share it with 4 devices on my WLAN, so I got an idea to implement a caching proxy, which will cache frequently downloaded resources. The most energy efficient device, which is always on, is a rooted Android tablet. So is there any web caching proxy server for Android? If not, how can I easily implement one?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a port of Polipo caching proxy for Android called [Polipoid](https://github.com/niutech/polipoid).